# Are there standard iOS Icons I could use in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

are there standard iOS Icons I could use in Xcode?

I want to add some standard icons from iOS like add or edit to buttons.

Comment: Check this out
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/system-icons/

Comment: this is what i was looking for, post this as an answer and i will accept it